# How to select rows for some employees, but no rows for others

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle18c

I have a table EMP that contains emplyee name and insurance plan selections.  There are multiple rows for employees because they can choose a new plan each year.  There are no null values allowed in any field.

How do I select all rows for employees that have a Plan of A or B, but no rows for any employee with a Plan of C?

EMP Table

```
Name    | Date   |  Plan |  
John    | 1/2018 |  A    |  
John    | 1/2017 |  B    |  
Alice   | 1/2018 |  C    |  
Bob     | 1/2018 |  A    |  
Bob     | 1/2017 |  C    |  
Bob     | 1/2016 |  B    |  
Dave    | 1/2018 |  B    |  
Dave    | 1/2017 |  B    |
```

The results should be:

```
John    1/2018  A  
John    1/2017  B  
Dave    1/2018  B  
Dave    1/2017  B
```

In other words, I want to select anyone with Plan A or B, but ignore all rows for anyone who ever had plan C.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, MySql, etc?

Comment: If an employee have plan A,B,D. Do the row with `D` also appear on only `A,B` ??

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say I'm using Oracle 18c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP
WHERE Name IN ( SELECT Name
                FROM EMP
                GROUP BY Name
                HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN Plan IN ('A','B') THEN 1 END) > 0
                   AND COUNT( CASE WHEN Plan = 'C' THEN 1 END) = 0
              )
```

Comment: Thanks, I always have trouble with "Group By".  This helped me understand it better, and it works!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select e.*
from emp e
where plan in ('A', 'B') and
      not exists (select 1
                  from emp e2
                  where e2.name = e.name and e2.plan = 'C'
                 );
```